# Parse and retrieve timezone offset from date-time

Tags: java, date, datetime

Date format: "**yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ**"

Input date: "**2017-09-18T03:08:20.888+0200**"

Problem: I need retrieve timezone offset from the input String and print the parsed date in this timezone. In other words, I need output to be the same as the input.

`SimpleDateFormat` parses input date successfully and returns `java.util.Date` object. [As we know](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), Date does not have timezone field. `SimpleDateFormat` converts parsed date to its timezone, which is, by default, system timezone. When I print this date, it is printed in System timezone.

Simple demo

```
private static void runDemoTask() throws ParseException {
    final String dateTimeTimezoneFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ";
    final SimpleDateFormat inputSdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateTimeTimezoneFormat);
    final String inputDate = "2017-09-18T01:08:20.888+0200";

    Date parsedDate = inputSdf.parse(inputDate);

    final SimpleDateFormat outputSdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateTimeTimezoneFormat);
    //outputSdf.setTimeZone("X_TIMEZONE_WHICH_I_NEED");
    String output = outputSdf.format(parsedDate);
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Output

```
Mon Sep 18 00:08:20 GMT+01:00 2017
```

Note, output date has system timezone, which is different from input string.

Note, I will not use **java.time**, **Joda Time** and other libraries because I need to support existing code.

---

**Possible *unpleasant* solution**

I tried to use regular expression to retrieve sign and offset.

```
private static  String parseTimeZone(String input) {
    final int singGroup = 1;
    final int offsetGroup = 2;
    final String timezonePatternStr = "([+-])(\\d{4})$";
    final Pattern timezonePattern = Pattern.compile(timezonePatternStr);

    Matcher matcher = timezonePattern.matcher(input);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        String sign = matcher.group(singGroup);
        String offset = matcher.group(offsetGroup);
        System.out.println(sign + " " + offset);
    }

    return "";
}
```

It prints

```
+ 0200
```

Comment: Well, you could extract the timezone part via regex but do you really need it? After all a date is the same single point in time no matter in which timezone, that's why it doesn't have one. When displaying that timezone to a user you could use their (preferred) timezone, which could be just another one.

Comment: Yeah, I updated my question.

Comment: Nitpicking, +0200 is not a time zone, it’s an offset from UTC. I suppose that this is what you need? Straightforward with `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API: `OffsetDateTime.parse("2017-09-18T03:08:20.888+0200").getOffset()`.

Comment: Yes, I need offset. I will update my question.

Comment: Side note on your regex: `([+]|[-])` can be simplified to `([+-])`, since `[...]` is a character class that matches _any one_ of the chars listed. If the minus isn't the first or last character it would need to be escaped though or otherwise it would be interpreted as defining a range like `a-z`.

Comment: Wait.  What version is your "existing code" running on?  If you *could* use Java 8 your job would be so much simpler.

Comment: Java 8. Probably, I will use java.time library in that place of code...

Comment: Regarding not using *java.time* classes because of existing old code, note that the old date-time classes have new methods for converting to/from java.time objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SimpleDateFormat` extends `DateFormat` and thus internally uses a `Calendar`. When parsing the date that calendar is being updated so you can get the timezone from it *after* parsing:

```
//use the timezone of the internally stored calendar
outputSdf.setTimeZone( inputSdf.getTimezone() );
```

That also shows why `DateFormat` is not threadsafe.

**EDIT:**

It seems the internal calendar's timezone **isn't updated** but the ZONE_OFFSET field is. Hence you could do something like this:

```
int zoneOffset = inputSdf.getCalendar().get( Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET );
//length check etc. left for you
String matchingZoneId = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs( zoneOffset )[0];
outputSdf.setTimeZone( TimeZone.getTimeZone( matchingZoneId ) );
```

Note that you can't just set the zone offset of the output format since that won't update the timezone reference which is used when formatting.

As you can see doing it this way looks a little "hacky" and thus you should think hard on whether you *really* need the timezone. In most cases you'd define the output timezone in a different way anyways, e.g. by getting the user's location, input, etc.

Comment: That does not work for me. `inputSdf.getTimezone()` returns my system timezone `-0600` and not `+0200`.

Comment: @tsolakp you're right, since I'm in the OP's timezone I got tricked. Will check this again.

Comment: @YanKhonski did you call that _after_ parsing? When I call it before parsing I get 3600000 as well since the initial timezone will be the system timezone which is +0100. After parsing I get 7200000.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you, guys: @Thomas, @ole-v-v

```
final DateTimeFormatter inputSdf1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateTimeTimezoneFormat);
OffsetDateTime d = OffsetDateTime.parse(inputDate, inputSdf1);

ZoneOffset zo = d.getOffset();  //Offset from the input.
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(zo.normalized());

outputSdf.setTimeZone(tz);
System.out.println(outputSdf.format(parsedDate));
```

Comment: Glad you found a working solution. Normally I’d say since you can use `java.time`, the modern date and time API, go all in and skip the outdated classes `TimeZone`, `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` completely. If you need to pass an object of one of those types to a legacy method that you cannot afford to change, you do need to convert, of course. I recommend you do so in the last moment before calling the legacy method as to use the modern API as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
TimeZone.getTimeZone(       // Convert from modern java.time type (`ZoneOffset`/`ZoneId`) to legacy type (`TimeZone`)
    OffsetDateTime.parse (  // Instantiate a `OffsetDateTime`, a moment on the timeline.
        "2017-09-18T03:08:20.888+0200" ,
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX" )
    ).getOffset()           // Extract a `ZoneOffset`, which is a subclass of `ZoneId`.
)
```

## Convert directly from modern `ZoneOffset` to legacy `TimeZone`

The code seen here is similar to Answers by Yan Khonski, but using the variation of [`TimeZone.getTimeZone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getTimeZone-java.time.ZoneId-) that directly converts from the modern java.time classes (`ZoneOffset` & `ZoneID`) to the legacy `TimeZone` class.

While there is no difference in the end result, this approach uses a an explicit conversion method. This is one of many new methods added to the old date-time classes for converting to/from java.time objects.

Using such a conversion method makes your code more self-documenting. Also makes more clear your awareness that you are consciously moving between the modern & legacy classes.

```
String input = "2017-09-18T03:08:20.888+0200";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX" );

OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input , f );  // Parse input.
ZoneOffset offset = odt.getOffset( );                    // Interrogate for the `ZoneOffset` object representing this moment’s offset-from-UTC (a number of hours/minutes/seconds).

TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone( offset );            // Convert from modern java.time object (a `ZoneOffset`/`ZoneId`) to the legacy class `TimeZone`.
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "odt.toString(): " + odt );
System.out.println( "offset.toString(): " + offset );
System.out.println( "tz.toString(): " + tz );
```

> odt.toString(): 2017-09-18T03:08:20.888+02:00
>
> offset.toString(): +02:00
>
> tz.toString(): sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT+02:00",offset=7200000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null]

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Hardcore solution!

Parse timezone and retrieve hours and minutes and sign and build a timezone!

```
public class ParseTimeZone {

    private static final String TIME_ZONE_REGEX = "([+-])(\\d{2})[:]?(\\d{2})$";
    private static final Pattern TIME_ZONE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(TIME_ZONE_REGEX);

    private static final int SING_GROUP = 1;
    private static final int HOURS_GROUP = 2;
    private static final int MINUTES_GROUP = 3;

    private static final String PLUS = "+";
    private static final String MINUS = "-";

    private static final int MINUTES_IN_HOUR = 60;
    private static final int SECONDS_IN_MINUTE = 60;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String inputDate = "2017-09-18T01:08:20.888Z";
        parseTimeZone(inputDate);
    }

    private static String parseTimeZone(String input) {
        input = fixDateStringWithZeroZoneOffset(input);
        Matcher matcher = TIME_ZONE_PATTERN.matcher(input);
        if (!matcher.find()) {
            return "";
        }

        String sign = matcher.group(SING_GROUP);
        String hours = matcher.group(HOURS_GROUP);
        String minutes = matcher.group(MINUTES_GROUP);

        int offsetSeconds = calculateOffsetSeconds(sign, hours, minutes);

        ZoneOffset zoneOffset = ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds(offsetSeconds);
        System.out.println(zoneOffset);

        TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(zoneOffset);
        System.out.println(timeZone);

        return "";
    }

    private static int calculateOffsetSeconds(String signStr, String hoursStr, String minutesStr) {
        try {
            int hours = Integer.parseInt(hoursStr);
            int minutes = Integer.parseInt(minutesStr);
            int sign = parseSign(signStr);

            int seconds = sign * ((hours * MINUTES_IN_HOUR + minutes) * SECONDS_IN_MINUTE);
            return seconds;

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("It should not happen because it matches the regular expression. There should be numbers.", e);
        }
    }

    private static int parseSign(String sign) {
        if (sign.equals(PLUS)) {
            return 1;
        } else if (sign.equals(MINUS)) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Offset sign should be + or -.");
        }
    }

    private static String fixDateStringWithZeroZoneOffset(String dateString) {
        if (dateString.endsWith("Z")) {
            return dateString.replaceAll("Z$", "+0000");
        }
        return dateString;
    }
}
```