# Convert OffSetDateTime String to ZonedDateTime Java

Tags: java, datetime

I have string of the pattern `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"` which I want to convert to `ZonedDateTime` format using Java.

Input String Example: `"2019-11-23T10:32:15+12:24"`

Output: `ZonedDateTime`

Edit: I have tried this but it does not work.

```
   ZonedDateTime convertToZonedDateTime(final String source) {
    final DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = dateFormat.parse(source);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());

}
```

I have this solution which works for string "2018-04-05 19:58:55" produces output 2018-04-05T19:58:55+05:30[Asia/Kolkata] but when I change the pattern in function to "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ" and input string to 2019-11-23T10:32:15+12:24 it does not work due to ParseException: Unparsable data.

I need ZonedDateTime format for an API which expects the input time in that format.

Comment: What have you done so far to solve it?

Comment: Added the required information

Comment: Any reason you need a `ZonedDateTime` rather than an `OffsetDateTime`? You really don't have a time zone here - you have an offset.

Comment: That offset of `+12:24` looks wrong, not mapping to any time zone. Are you sure it is correct? Can you explain the source?

Comment: You’re mixing outdated and modern date/time classes. I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `DateTimeFormatter` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: You seem to have provided some further information in the comments to some of the answers. Please edit your question and gather all the information there. It’s much nicer to have everything in one place. Many, including myself, are not trawling through all the comments to get the full understanding of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime                       // Represent a moment as a date with time-of-day in the context of an offset-from-UTC (a number of hours-minutes-seconds).
.parse(                              // Parse text into a date-time object.
    "2019-11-23T10:32:15+12:24"      // The offset of +12:24 looks suspicious, likely an error.
)                                    // Returns an `OffsetDateTime` object.
```

Semantically, we are done at this point with a [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) object in hand.

But you claim to be using an API that demands a [`ZoneDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object. We have no known time zone to apply, so let’s apply UTC (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds).

```
OffsetDateTime                       // Represent a moment as a date with time-of-day in the context of an offset-from-UTC (a number of hours-minutes-seconds).
.parse(                              // Parse text into a date-time object.
    "2019-11-23T10:32:15+12:24"      // The offset of +12:24 looks suspicious, likely an error.
)                                    // Returns an `OffsetDateTime` object.
.atZoneSameInstant(                  // Convert from `OffsetDateTime` to `ZonedDateTime` by applying a time zone.
    ZoneOffset.UTC                   // This constant is a `ZoneOffset` object, whose class extends from `ZoneId`. So we can use it as a time zone, though semantically we are making a mess. 
)                                    // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
.toString()                          // Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format.
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/FUw3wA).

> 2019-11-22T22:08:15Z

Caveat: The offset on your example input string looks wrong to me.

## Details

You need to understand some concepts for date-time handling.

### Offset

A offset-from-UTC is merely a number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead of, or behind, the meridian line drawn at the Greenwich Royal Observatory.

In Java, we represent an offset with the `ZoneOffset` class. A date and time-of-day in the context of an offset is represented with the `OffsetDateTime` class. Such an object represents a moment, a specific point on the timeline.

### Time zone

A time zone is much more. A time zone is a history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region. These changes are determined by politicians. So these changes can be arbitrary and capricious, and happen surprisingly often, often with little or no warning. In North America, for example, most regions have adopted Daylight Saving Time (DST) nonsense, resulting in the offset changing twice a year. Currently there is a fad amongst politicians to quit DST changes while staying permanently year-round on “summer time”, one hour ahead of standard time.

There is a database cataloging these changes. The *tZ data* is a file maintained by IANA listing changes worldwide. You’ll likely find copies of this data in your host OS, in enterprise-quality database management systems such as *Postgres*, and in your Java Virtual Machine. Be sure to keep these up-to-date with changes in zones you care about.

Time zones have names in the format of `Continent/Region`. For example, `Africa/Tunis`, `Europe/Paris`, and `Asia/Kolkata`.

### `OffsetDateTime`

So an input string like "2019-11-23T10:32:15+12:24" has no indicator of time zone, only an offset. So we must parse it an a `OffsetDateTime`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2019-11-23T10:32:15+12:24" ) ;
```

**Asking for that as a `ZonedDateTime` makes no sense.** We cannot reliably determine a time zone merely from an offset. Many time zones may share an offset for some pints in time.

Also, that particular input string `2019-11-23T10:32:15+12:24` is suspect. That offset of twelve hours and twenty-four minutes does not map to any current time zone. Are you sure it is correct?

You can convert your `OffsetDateTime` to a `ZonedDateTime` by specifying a time zone to use in adjustment. I suggest using UTC. While this works technically, semantically it is confusing. Moments in UTC are best represented by `OffsetDateTime` rather than `ZonedDateTime`. But apparently you are interoperating with code that demands a `ZonedDateTime` specifically, so *c’est la vie*.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

### `Instant`

Tip: Generally, APIs should be written to hand off moments as an `Instant` object, which is always in UTC by definition.

### `LocalDateTime`

You present another string input, "2018-04-05 19:58:55". This input lacks any indicator of time zone or offset-from-UTC. So we cannot know if this means almost-8PM in Tokyo Japan, or almost-8PM in Toulouse France, or almost-8PM in Toledo Ohio US — which are all events happening several hours apart, different points on the time zone.

Such a value must be parsed as a `LocalDateTime`. Replace the SPACE in the middle with a `T` to comply with ISO 8601 standard formatting.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "2018-04-05 19:58:55".replace( " " , "T" ) ) ;
```

The resulting object does not represent a moment, is not a point in the timeline. Such an object represents *potential* moments along a spectrum of about 26-27 hours, the range of time zones around the globe.

### `ZonedDateTime`

If you are certain that input string was intended for a particular time zone, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`. Then you have determined a moment, a specific point on the timeline.

```
ZoneId z = ZonedId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;
```

---

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: is this a zoned date time 2018-06-20T01:30:51.468Z?

Comment: @idk See the “tl;dr” section I added up top. `2019-11-23T10:32:15+12:24` adjusted to UTC is `2019-11-22T22:08:15Z`.

Comment: Thanks, I will check by sending the api request if it works

Answer (score 2):

You can parse the input date time string into [OffsetDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) and then convert it into [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html)

```
String inputDate = "2019-11-23T10:32:15+12:24";

OffsetDateTime offset = OffsetDateTime.parse(inputDate);

ZonedDateTime dateTime = offset.toZonedDateTime();
```

If you just need `ZonedDateTime` at same local time with `ZoneId` then use `atZoneSimilarLocal`

```
ZonedDateTime dateTime = offset.atZoneSimilarLocal(ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

Comment: The output for this comes out to be 2019-11-23T10:32:15+12:24 . Isnt a timezone expected here ? source: https://www.baeldung.com/java-zoneddatetime-offsetdatetime

Comment: Not sure whether the `jodatime` tag used should be taken into account. May be worth pointing out that this is `java.time` (unless the 2 apis are fully compatible)

Comment: @idk If your intent is to convert it to a zoned date time with a standard time zone, then you may want to [read through this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48291259/5761558)

Comment: For that particular offset i'm not getting any `TimeZones` can you be more specific with some expected output @idk

Comment: still you haven't show expected output ? you want to convert input string into specific zone or just append zone id to that time ? @idk

Comment: want to append zone id in the format of ZonedDateTime. Not String

Comment: is this a zoned date time 2018-06-20T01:30:51.468Z?

Comment: Yes with zone UTC @idk

Answer (score 0):

It’s unclear why you think you want a `ZonedDateTime`, and if you do, in which time zone. A bit of the following has been said already, but I would like to give you three suggestions to choose from:

1. You don’t need a `ZonedDateTime`. An `OffsetDateTime` fits your string better.
2. If you want a `ZonedDateTime` in your default time zone, which makes sense, use `OffsetDateTime.atZoneSameInstant()` (as in the answer by Basil Bourque).
3. If you just want a `ZonedDateTime` representation of your string, the one-arg `ZonedDateTime.parse()` parses it directly.

### Use OffsetDateTime

Your string contains an offset, `+12:34`, and not a time zone, like Pacific/Galapagos. So `OffsetDateTime` is more correct to represent its content.

```
    String inputStringExample = "2019-11-23T10:32:15+12:24";
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(inputStringExample);
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

Output from this snippet is:

> 2019-11-23T10:32:15+12:24

I agree with the comment by Basil Bourque, the offset of `+12:24` doesn’t look like a real-world UTC offset, but it’s fine for a Stack Overflow example. In 2019 most offsets are on a whole hour and the rest generally on a whole quarter of an hour, so 24 minutes is not used. Historic offsets include many with both minutes and seconds.

I am exploiting the fact that your string is in ISO 8601 format. The classes of java.time parse the most common ISO 8601 variants as their default, that is, without any explicit formatter. Which is good because writing a format pattern string is always error-prone.

### Use OffsetDateTime.atZoneSameInstant()

Your call to `ZoneId.systemDefault()` in the code in the question seems to suggest that you want a `ZonedDateTime` in your default time zone. On one hand this use of `ZonedDateTime` seems reasonable and sound. On the other hand relying on `ZoneId.systemDefault()` is shaky since the default time zone of your JVM can be changed at any time by another part of your program or any ther program running in the same JVM.

```
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(inputStringExample)
            .atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

Output in my time zone:

> 2019-11-22T23:08:15+01:00[Europe/Copenhagen]

### Parse directly

If you just need a `ZonedDateTIme` for an API that requires one (for most purposes a poor design), just parse your string into one:

```
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(inputStringExample);
```

> 2019-11-23T10:32:15+12:24

Output is indistinguishable from the one we got from `OffsetDateTime`, but you have got the required type now.

### Stay far away from SimpleDateFormat and Date

In the code in your question you tried to use `SimpleDateFormat` for parsing your string. Since you can use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, stick to it and forget everything about the old date and time classes. The modern API gives you all the functionality you need. In case we had needed a formatter for parsing, the modern `DateTimeFormatter` would have been the class to use.

### What went wrong in your code?

> … it does not work due to ParseException: Unparsable data.

`Z` in your format pattern string is for RFC 822 time zone offset. This is without colon and would have parsed `+1224`, but not `+12:24`.

### Link

- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)