# Cannot convert String pattern to ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, string, datetime, datetime-parsing, zoneddatetime

I'm stuck on a conversion problem from a String to a ZonedDateTime in Java.

I have the following String :

```
String str = "2019-06-13T09:27:07.233+0000";
```

that I would like to convert to a `ZonedDateTime`. So far I've been trying with and without formatters but I keep getting an error.
Here's my code :

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
return ZonedDateTime.parse(str, formatter);
```

The error I get is :

```
Text '2019-06-13T09:27:07.233+0000' could not be parsed at index 23.
```

I've tried several custom patterns as well as `ISO_DATE_TIME` and `ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` but none of them worked...

Anyone would have any idea of the correct pattern for this one ?

Thank you !

Comment: Your pattern specifies a literal letter Z. Your string does not end with literally the letter Z. Remove the two `'` around Z.

Comment: @Michael Indeed, it appears to be working with pattern "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse and retrieve timezone offset from date-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48230408/parse-and-retrieve-timezone-offset-from-date-time)